# unexpected characters preceding filenames when using LS

Tags: openwrt, arduino

We have an Arduino Yun Rev 2 with extroot set up via the YunDiskExpander sketch onto a 32 GB sandisk microSD partitioned to have 512 MB for the extroot.

Oddly however whenever we use ls the results are prefaced with a `[` a digit (typically `1`) a `;` two more digits (typically `34`) the letter `m` and then we get the file or folder name, which then always has `[m` appended to it. This also seems to occur on every character when vim is run on the Arduino.

We are accessing it via the publicly available serial monitor as terminal sketch. These unexpected characters are notably hindering development, as such any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That appears to be the problem, thank you very much! ls --color=no did remove the strange characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you described are (parts of) [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) responsible for changing the foreground color of text. In my Debian `ls` may generate the following example output:

```
^[[01;34mfoobar^[[0m
```

where `^[` represents a single character: escape character (`0x1b`). Terminals that support this, after receiving such data should print `foobar` in blue. You didn't mention zeros and my tests indicate that `^[[1;34mfoobar^[[m` works as well, so probably your `ls` generates the latter form.

`ls` tries to colorize its output but it looks like escape characters are lost in transmission for whatever reason or they are transmitted correctly but your terminal ignores them (neither prints their representation nor recognizes control sequences that follow). In effect you see:

```
[1;34mfoobar[m
```

Pure `ls` without options shouldn't use colors, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) says nothing about colors. Still, implementations may give you an option to colorize output and it's common for `ls` to be an alias to `ls --color=auto`. Usually this works well and users may not even know the alias is involved. Check if this scenario fits your case: invoke `alias ls`. I assume it does.

Possible solutions:

- override the option on demand: `ls --color=no`;
- bypass the alias on demand: `command ls`;
- destroy the alias (once per shell session): `unalias ls`;
- find out in which startup script the alias is defined and delete the relevant line or comment it out; this is a permanent solution.